# Trying ru script in the loop to see if services on Remote Server (s) is running

Tags: powershell, variables

Originally I had a script:

```
Do {
    Get-Date
    Write-Output "SERVER01";
    gsv -cn SERVER01 -Name Dm* |out-string
    Write-Output "SERVER02";
    gsv -cn SERVER02 -Name Dm* |out-string
    sleep 60
}
while ($true)
```

I am trying to make Server(s) name and service a variable

```
Do {
    Get-Date
    $name = Read-Host 'What is your ServerName?'
    $srv = Read-Host 'What is ServiceName?'
    write-host $name
    gsv -cn $name -Name $srv |out-string
    sleep 60
}
```

Please help me to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code other than you assumedly only want to prompt for the server name and service name once and then check them repeatedly. In which case, move your `read-host` lines to before the `Do` loop:

```
$name = Read-Host 'What is your ServerName?'
$srv = Read-Host 'What is ServiceName?'

Do {
    Get-Date
    Write-Host $name
    gsv -cn $name -Name "$srv*" | Out-String
    Sleep 60
}
while ($true)
```

I've also added the wildcard `*` character back into your retrieval of the services, per your original script, so that you can return services based on a partial name.